# How to remove paranthesis but keep the text in it in R

Tags: r, brackets

I am trying to clean a dataset with the column: ltaCpInfoDF$weekdays_rate_1

For some of the rows, I would like to do this:

> **input:** Daily(7am-11pm): $1.20 ; **output:** 7am-11pm: $1.20

The values within the bracket can be different timings for the rows.

Initially, I was thinking of removing by part such as removing "Daily(" with gsub first then removing ")". However, I seem to be facing issues with that.

```
ltaCpInfoDF$weekdays_rate_1 <- gsub("Daily(", "", ltaCpInfoDF$weekdays_rate_1)
```

Here is the error shown:

```
Error in gsub("Daily(", "", ltaCpInfoDF$weekdays_rate_1) : 
  invalid regular expression 'Daily(', reason 'Missing ')''
In addition: Warning message:
In gsub("Daily(", "", ltaCpInfoDF$weekdays_rate_1) :
  TRE pattern compilation error 'Missing ')''
```

Could someone share with me a better way? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to learn that some character in regex patterns need to be escaped

Comment: Are you looking for `ltaCpInfoDF$weekdays_rate_1 <- gsub("Daily\\(", "", ltaCpInfoDF$weekdays_rate_1)` ? Even using `sub` should do I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sub` with a capture group:

```r
input <- "Daily(7am-11pm): $1.20"
output <- gsub("\\S+\\s*\\((.*?)\\)", "\\1", input)
output

[1] "7am-11pm: $1.20"
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use without capturing

```
gsub("^[^(]+\\(|\\)", "", str1)
[1] "7am-11pm: $1.20"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "Daily(7am-11pm): $1.20"
```